# uwp connect to sql

Tags: database, win-universal-app

I am writing an uwp app, and I need to store data to cloud database. I used google cloud sql service and I can manage my database by cmd[image]
but when I tried to connect google cloud sql with C#, erro occurs:"System.NotImplementedException"(in MySql.Data.RT.dll)
Here is my code:

```
MySqlConnection mc = new MySqlConnection();
            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder s = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            s.Server = "146.148.112.96";              
            s.UserID = "root";
            s.Database = "Bridge";
            s.Password = "******";
            mc.ConnectionString = s.ToString();
            try
            {
                mc.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd = mc.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from userInfo where name='" + usertextBox.Text + "' where nikyname='" + nicktextBox1.Text + "'";
                MySqlDataReader mdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                mdr.Read();
                if (mdr.HasRows)
                {
                    MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("Username/Nickname invalid!");
                    await msg.ShowAsync();
                    insert = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    insert = true;
                }
                mc.Close();
            }
```

Can anyone teach me waht I should do ? thanks

Comment: I haven't tried Google's cloud yet, but are you open to using Azure? If so, I can provide more info. But I wanted to check with you first before going any further.

Comment: thanks,i can use azure, please give me mor info,it could be great if you have code example :)

Comment: Sure, I'll add an answer based on your new request :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your extended request in the comments, here are some resources (with code samples) to create UWP apps with a DB on Azure.

UWP, Azure App Services, and DocumentDB
* https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/17/uwp-azure-app-services-and-documentdb-soup-a-photo-sharing-app/

Source code on GitHub
* https://github.com/Microsoft/Appsample-Photosharing

There are many different ways to do this, but this should help you get started